# Draw particles on canvas from array position

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw

I have been using a particle system to draw on a `<canvas>`, and now I'm trying to create an "image" out of particles from an array.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out how to position and color the particles according to how the array is structured.

The array I'm trying to make the image out of is the "defs" array.  Hopefully I'm close to achieving my goal, but I need some help.

Here's what I've got.

`0 = White`
`1 = Black`
`2 = Red`

(Stackoverflow wouldn't let me enter in the Javascript for some reason, here is a link to the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/arcbpred/)

```js
// Creating the Canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    particles = {},
    particleIndex = 0,
    particleNum = 87;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.id = "canvas";

// Setting needed varialbes
var xmin = 1;
var xmax = +canvas.width;
var bgcolor = "#FFF";

// Setting color which is just one big square
c.fillStyle = bgcolor;
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var defs = {
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1], [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
};

function Particle() {
  this.x = canvas.width / 2 - 15;
  this.y = canvas.height / 2 / 2;

  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;

  this.gravity = 0;

  particleIndex++;
  particles[particleIndex] = this;
  this.id = particleIndex;
  this.beat = 1;

  this.size = 30;
  this.color = "rgba(191,30,46,0)";




}

Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;
  this.vy += this.gravity;



  c.fillStyle = this.color;
  c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
};

setInterval(function() {
  c.fillStyle = bgcolor;
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
    new Particle();
  }
  for (var i in particles) {
    particles[i].draw();
  }
}, 30);
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(100,0,0,1);
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Thank you for any input.

Comment: I meant "defs" not "Def" sorry.

Comment: It depends on how you want to achive this. You get a single-Array out of the context of a canvas. Should every pixel be modified? Then your defs-array might not be big enough for all pixels. Each Array-element of defs can be considered as row of the image and each number-element as pixel. So you have to make sure that refs is big enough.

Comment: Sorry, for one more ;) You have got a Particle-Object why do you have to use an array to determine how an image should look?

Comment: As you can see in this CodePen (http://codepen.io/darrylhuffman/pen/VYbxKy/), I am using if statements in this Particle-Object to move them according to their ID.  So, I was trying to use an array to move them accordingly, but in a cleaner fashion.  The design I made there I wanted to make in an array that looked like [1,2,1]

Comment: A finished version of what I was attempting to make is here - http://codepen.io/darrylhuffman/pen/WbMzNm    | Only issue is the code is nasty, it's about 97 if statements to move the particles...